# Android - Can all Android versions receive Firebase push notifications

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, xamarin.android, firebase-cloud-messaging

We are building a Xamarin project and we are using Firebase as our push notification service. However we have picked up that on lower versions of Android the push notifications aren't coming through.

Is there any minimum Android version requirement for Xamarin Android Firebase Messaging?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the official documentation:

> FCM clients require devices running Android 4.0 or higher that also
>   have the Google Play Store app installed, or an emulator running
>   Android 4.0 with Google APIs. Note that you are not limited to
>   deploying your Android apps through Google Play Store.

Comment: Thank you, just the answer I was looking for.